# Getting Exchange Email Through a Cisco VPN ?

Tags: email, vpn

Is there a way to get my email from my works exchange server if I need to connect using a Cisco Any Connect VPN client?

I can't find an Any Connect Client for Android and I've tried connecting to the mail server directly but it (Obviously) can't resolve the host because it's behind a VPN.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has just pointed out that ICS will include Cisco Any Connect functionality...

http://www.talkandroid.com/69015-cisco-anyconnect-vpn-support-to-be-implemented-in-ice-cream-sandwich-enterprise-users-rejoice/

Upon Further investigation there is an Any Connect Client for Android, but you need to have rooted your phone to use it:
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cisco.anyconnect.vpn.android.rooted&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5jaXNjby5hbnljb25uZWN0LnZwbi5hbmRyb2lkLnJvb3RlZCJd